# How to invoke a process sleeping on poll function by another thread in the same process with signal without killing it?

Tags: c++, linux, signals, file-descriptor

I want to manually wake up (by another thread in the same process) a thread sleeping on poll() function waiting for any input data available. Looks like I found a possible solution by sending signals, but I don't have any experience with them really. On this page I [found](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) a signal called SIGPOLL with codes like POLL_IN, POLL_MSG, but when I call it, the whole process is killed.
How to send this signal without killing the whole process ?

Comment: If the thread you want to communicate with is already `poll`ing why not just use a [pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) to communicate with it?

Comment: @G.M. Thank you. Didn't think about it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used pipe() to solve this problem.

```
void a(int invokefd){
     ...
     write(invokefd, "c", 1);
     ...
}

void b(int invokefd){
     vector<pollfd> readfds;
     ...
     pollfd invfd;
     invfd.fd = invokefd;
     invfd.events = POLLIN;
     invfd.revents = 0;
     readfds.push_back(invfd);
     ...
     poll(&readfds[0], readfds.size(), -1);
     ...
}

void main(){
     ...
     int invokedfs[2];
     pipe(invokefds);
     thread aTh(a, invokefds[1]);
     thread bTh(b, invokefds[0]);
     ...
}
```

Comment: Read also [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [socket(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html), [unix(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), [mkfifo(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html), [fifo(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [sem_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), [shm_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview(7)). Consider using [libevent](https://libevent.org/), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [Qt](https://qt.io/)